# MySQL tomcat JDBC Connection pool testOnBorrow check does not get a response

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

My Application is using a tomcat JDBC Connection pool to connect to a remote MySQL database with the following connection pool configurations,

```
maxActive: 80
maxWait: 60000
minIdle: 5
testOnBorrow: true
validationQuery: SELECT 1
validationInterval: 30000
validationQueryTimeout: 10
```

Most of the time everything works fine but occasionally the application seems to get stuck when executing the **testOnBorrow** on the connection pool. This was discovered by enabling Java Flight Recorder and it showed the following stack trace,

```
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int)
com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(int)
com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(byte[], int, int)  
com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(byte[], int, int)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(Buffer, int)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(Buffer)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(int)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(int, String, Buffer, boolean, String, int)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(StatementImpl, String, String, Buffer, int, int, int, boolean, String, Field[])
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(StatementImpl, String, int, Buffer, int, int, boolean, String, Field[], boolean)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(StatementImpl, String, int, Buffer, int, int, boolean, String, Field[])
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(String, boolean)
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(String)
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(int, String)
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(int)
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(long, PooledConnection, String, String)
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(int, String, String)
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection()
```

So the above socket read takes place on the remote MySQL server on port 3306. The socket read lasts for approximately 15 minutes until my application times out with 0 bytes being read during this time according to the JFR recording. I do not see any SQL exceptions during this time. When my application times out and closes the connection I receive a *java.io.IOException: Broken pipe*.

This only occurs occasionally and subsequent calls do not run into this issue. I do not have direct access to the remote MySQL server or the network that my application is running on. Any idea what could cause this and how this can be overcome?

Comment: JDBC Pool being used is **tomcat-jdbc-7.0.47.jar**

Comment: Could it be a table lock issue? Do you have a possibility of a database deadlock? It looks like the error is occurring after it is executing the SQL statement, not before it gets the connection from the pool. If so, this is not an issue with the JDBC driver and you would need to get a view into the locks held by MySQL, not the JVM.

Comment: The table in question has only around twenty rows so I doubt that there is a table locking issue going on here. Got more information regarding the MySQL deployment, **MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition 5.5.8** is being used with **mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar**

Comment: It doesn't matter if there are only twenty rows - if you have one transaction request a range lock on a set of rows (say, for an UPDATE statement) and that transaction never commits (and thus still holds the lock until time out), the very next transaction that tries to read from those same set of rows could also be locked and spin forever until it too times out. Of course this will vary depending on the database and the transaction isolation levels, but the basic principle is the same. Is your transaction timeout 15 minutes?

Comment: Make you sure are either committing or rolling back all your transactions and that you are always closing your connections such that they get returned to the connection pool properly.